# Kentico Smart Search Results URL not linking

Tags: url, search, hyperlink, kentico

I've got a smart search box on one box and the results are displayed as expected on a results page - however the URL of each result just links to the results page and not to the document in question.

Anyone got any pointers as to what i'm doing wrong??

Comment: What does your transformation look like?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call method `SearchResultUrl(true)` in your transformation to get the URL.
See more in documentation http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?smart_search_transformations.htm